# Loop through every table row and insert different formula

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

i have a table with predefined rows and columns. I want to loop through every row and put a different formula into each cell. The cell should show data from a different worksheet. This step is to be repeated for every column.

```
                                      Repeat:
+--------+--------+-----+---------+  1 || 2 ->
|Column 1|Column 2| ... | Column n|  |
+--------+--------+-----+---------+  |
|row 1   | row 1  | ... | row 1   |  |
+--------+--------+-----+---------+  v
|                ...              |
+--------+--------+-----+---------+
|row n   | row n  | ... | row n   |
+--------+--------+-----+---------+
```

I tried using a for loop, which runs until the last row and places the formula with the .FormulaLocal method into the current cell.

```
For i = 1 To UBound(bmPos)
        curTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, curTable.ListColumns("Column1").Index).FormulaLocal = _
                "=Table1!" & wksBM.Cells(bmPos(i), rngDate.Column).Address
        [...]
        curTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, curTable.ListColumns("ColumnN").Index).FormulaLocal = _
                "=Table1!" & wksBM.Cells(bmPos(i), rngCustomer.Column).Address
Next i
```

The expected result is that each cell *i* contains a formula like this:
=Table1!$A$1 ... =Table1!$A$ *i*

What i see when i step through my code with the debugger is, that in the very first iteration, **all** rows get the same value. So after the last iteration, all rows contain the formula  =Table1!$A$ *i*

Infact, when I replace the whole formula with just *i*, I get the right iteration step in the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Excel Table is autofilling the whole column with the last Formula you entered on any Row.

To Prevent this, put `Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False` in the beginning of your Sub.